# Inside load balancer in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer, internal-load-balancer

In Azure, I have 3 Web Apps (for simplicity):

- Frontend website
- Endpoint 1
- Endpoint 2

The frontend website requests data from an endpoint.
Both endpoints are synchronized all the time (outside the scope of this question), but sometimes I need to do some maintenance on them, which gives me some downtime.

Can I somehow setup a loadbalancer **only** my frontend website can see, and get any of the online endpoints - like this:

[image]

The last line of [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/internal-load-balancing/) says Internal Load Balancers might be the fit:

> **Can I use ILB on PaaS services (Web/Worker roles)?**
>
> ILB is designed to work with web/worker roles as well, and it is available from SDK 2.4 onwards.

Does anyone know of a guide, or have tried making this with Web Apps?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is something you can achieve "natively" with load balancers. App Services are not actually bound to the VNet. Previously you could only use point-to-site vpn to connect them to vnet, right now there is a new [vnet integration feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) in preview which might allow you to use internal load balancers, but I doubt that, because they (load balancers) only allow to use virtual machines\scale sets\availability sets as backend pools.

[Application gateways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-web-app) can be bound to the App Services. And they can be internal as well. You'd also need to restrict App Service(s) to receive traffic from anything that is not you Application gateway.

You can use traffic manager\front door for this sort of load balancing, but the endpoints won't be private